# solr synonym multi word - bring synonym at top

Tags: solr

I am using solr search and everything is working fine, but if I put "video camera" synonym for "camcorder", it shows me all the results containing video, camera and camcorders which is perfectly fine.But is there a way to bring results for camcorder on the top and then show the rest.

Please help.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can create a separate field *textWithoutSynonyms* without synomym filter and boost that field:

```
<field name="text" type="text_general"/>
<field name="textWithoutSynonyms" type="text_general_without_synonyms"/>

<copyField source="text" dest="textWithoutSynonyms" />
```

Then Your search handler config may look like that:

```
<str name="qf">text textWithoutSynonyms^100</str>
```

Comment: Just a quick comment, this will work even with no boost, as it the query will find the non-synonym token in both fields, so it will naturally appear higher.